# VSTO Outlook: rendering and centering issues when showing a custom message box

Tags: outlook, vsto, interop, outlook-addin, office-addins

In some circumstances I am showing a message box, exactly when my WPF user control which is embedded within a custom task pane gets resized (its height). The WPF user control triggers the resize event when the custom task pane (located at top) gets resized. The message box is a custom WPF user control that is embedded within an ElementHost.Through the elementhost I can display it in the Outlook Add-in side (which in fact it is a winforms app).

I have tried to approaches to show the custom WPF message box:

1. Showing it using the main UI thread
2. Showing it using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer

If I use first approach, the custom WPF message box is correctly rendered and shown but it is not centered correctly in the Outlook workspace. However, if I use the second approach, the custom WPF message box is correctly centered in the Outlook main window but then it is not correctly rendered and shown at all, I mean, the bottom border of the message box is not drawn.

The border in the WPF user control (message box) is as below:

```
    <Border BorderBrush="#BEBEBE"
            BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">
```

So why I am getting these weird behaviors? I need the message box to be centered in the Outlook window and shown/drawn correctly. Some things work in the first approach and others in the second one. How can I do this?